# Configure BrowserStack in Angular 4 project developed in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, browserstack

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my test suite in `BrowserStack`.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {Contacts} from '../Contacts.po';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
```

Why does it not recognize keyword import? P.S Note: The whole project developed using typescript and I have compiled this project into to js then running my test suite. In local it working but in browerstack I'm getting the error. I'm using `protractor` and `jasmine`.

Comment: Shouldn't be BrowserStack's issue as the failure is in import statement. This means your compiler/interpreter fails to understand it. If this is working locally please share your local selenium setup details (selenium server version, webdriver version, webbrowser details).

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your project during compilation for typescript. Add the below lines of code to the before launch function of browserstack config file.

```
// Code to start browserstack local before start of test
beforeLaunch: function(){
    require('ts-node').register({
        project: './e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
      });
    console.log("Connecting local");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        exports.bs_local = new browserstack.Local();
        exports.bs_local.start({'key': exports.config.capabilities['browserstack.key'] }, function(error) {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            console.log('Connected. Now testing...');

            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Below is how the tsconfig.e2e.json file is configured.

```
{
 "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
 "compileOnSave": true,
 "compilerOptions": {
 "outDir": "../out-tsc/e2e",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "target": "es5",
 "types":[
  "jasmine",
  "node"
 ]
}
}
```

This should resolve your issue. Thanks.